# click on features with some problems

Tags: openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to build a map with some features that are polygons, together they are a heat map which shows the number of issues in that area.

When I click on a feature, for now, it shows an alert that says "clicked", but some features does not fire the click action, some of them when I click, the click works, the others the click does not work.

Here is my code:

```
    var listaBairros = document.getElementById("lista-bairros").value;
var lotes = [];

lotes = lotes_parser();

var styles = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1)'
        })
    })
];

var styles15 = function () {
    return [new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'blue',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(80, 233, 179,1)'
        })
    })];
};

var styles610 = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'yellow',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(213, 236, 70, 1)'
        })
    })
];

var styles1115 = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'orange',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(246, 149, 56, 1)'
        })
    })
];

var styles15mais = [
    new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'purple',
            width: 3
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 0, 119, 1)'
        })
    })
];


var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({        
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    name: 'bairros'
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        doubleClickZoom: false,
        dragAndDrop: false,
        dragPan: false,
        keyboardPan: false,
        keyboardZoom: false,
        mouseWheelZoom: false,
        pointer: false,
        select: false
    }),
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attribution: false,
        zoom: false,
    }),
    layers: [vectorLayer],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-46.48758604980461, -23.9616060511448], 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 12
    })
});

map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
        function (feature) {
            return feature;
        });

    if (feature) {
        coord = map.getView().getCenter();            
        alert("clicked");
    }
});


assignFeaturesToPolygon();




function polygonToArray(entrada) {
    var removePolygon = entrada.replace("POLYGON ((", "").replace("))", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    var points = removePolygon.split(", ");
    var finalPoints = [];
    points.forEach(function (point) {
        var temporaryPoint = point.split(" ");
        temporaryPoint[0] = Number(temporaryPoint[0]);
        temporaryPoint[1] = parseFloat(temporaryPoint[1]);
        finalPoints.push(temporaryPoint);
    })
    return finalPoints;
}

function assignFeaturesToPolygon() {        
    lotes.forEach(function (value, index) {
        var new_feature = criarFeature(value);
        var teste = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);

        if (teste == 1) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles15);
        } else if (teste == 2) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles610);
        } else if (teste == 3) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles1115);
        } else if (teste == 4) {
            new_feature.setStyle(styles15mais);
        }
        vectorSource.addFeature(new_feature);            
    });
};

function criarFeature(geometria) {
    var feature = new ol.Feature(
        new ol.geom.Polygon([geometria])
    );

    feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    return feature;
}


function lotes_parser() {
    var bairros_separados = [];
    var bairros_parser = listaBairros.split(" _ ");
    bairros_parser.forEach(function (lote, index) {
        bairros_separados.push(polygonToArray(lote));
    });
    return bairros_separados;
}
```

This is all of my map code because I don't know what is really usefull to find an answer.

This is the input with the data that I'm working on:

https://pastebin.com/hXpng27j

I used pastebin because it is too many lines.

Another edit here:

In jsFiddle the code works perfectly, but in my C# Project it does not. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Link to jsFiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/5u95mwqb/

Comment: is that happening on pc web?

Comment: Can you add this code running a platform like jsfiddle? maybe we work on it.

Comment: Your issue would suggest that there is a problem with OL converting the click location pixels to coordinates that are then hit tested for features. Perhaps you could provide examples of the data being parsed and turned into features so we can see if there is something there.

Comment: I've just edited the question, now there is a link with the input with the data I'm working on.

Comment: Your code is fine, it is about; [> he reason alert() does not work is because previously you have checked "prevent this page from creating additional dialoug" checkbox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277406/javascript-why-sometimes-alert-does-not-work-but-console-log-does)

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there is another reason. Because I changed to console.log removing the alert, and I click in some features, more than one time, and still does not work :/